# Setting up a Like Counter on Rails from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Was trying to set up a ranking score for my users depending on their like counts.

I was able to get this to work for **current_user.like.count** but for some reason when I want it to be for **user.like.count** [so that its not the same one for everyone] my app crashes and gives me this error message: "Undefined method `likes' for nil:NilClass" I have put all my relevant code below as well as my github for this. Any help would be amazing.

Github Url: https://github.com/OmarZV/TY2

**_rankings.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.likes.count >3 %>
A Ranking
<% elsif %>
<% current_user.likes.count == 2%>
B Ranking
<% else %>
C Ranking
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @users = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :users, :controllers => "users_controller.rb"
  resources :users do
    resource :ranking, module: :users
  end
  resources :posts do
    resource :like, module: :posts
  end
  root to: "posts#index"
end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="page-header">Platform Users</h1>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<strong><%=  user.username %></strong>
<div class="round-image-50"><%= image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %></div>
div id="user_<%= @user_id%>_rankings">
<%= render partial: "rankings", locals: {user: @user} %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: user.like.count gives an error because user isnt set to anything.  User.first.like.count should give you the number of likes for the first user.  Not really sure what you mean about it not being the same for everyone. Current_user would be the current logged in user when using devise.   Also your show action instance variable should probably be singular as youre only finding one user based on the param.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. What I mean was - with "Current_user" its only showing the ranking for the current user and applying it to all the other users because there  is a loop. Its in the index.html.erb file that I just put in the question. So what I'm looking for is how can show the rankings for each user.

Comment: Id just loop through and not use a partial probably.  Im pretty sure you can just pass `locals: {user: user}` to use the variable from the loop and not the instance variable from your controller.  You could also change it to use a collection like this `<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products %>`  instead of the loop.  checkout the docs on it for a bit more details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: It works amazing by passing locals: {user: user} Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comment to answer.

Id just loop through and not use a partial probably. But im  pretty sure you can just pass `locals: {user: user}` to use the variable from the loop and not the instance variable from your controller. checkout the docs on it for a bit more details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials